# Expected value and variance: $Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$

Tags: probability

My notes claim the following:

> The **variance** of a random variable $X$ is
>
> $$Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2]$$
>
> $\dots$
>
> For any random variable $X$,
>
> $Var[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$

I'm wondering how it is that $Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$?

We have that

$$Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - 2XE[X] + (E[X])^2 \not= E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Denote: $E(X)=\mu$. Then: $$Var(X)=E((X-\mu)^2)=E(X^2-2\mu X+\mu^2)=E(X^2)-2\mu E(X)+\mu^2=\\E(X^2)-\mu^2=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - 2E[XE[X]] + (E[X])^2 =E[X^2] - 2E[X]E[X] + (E[X])^2  $$
that is
$$Var[X] =E[X^2] - 2(E[X])^2 + (E[X])^2  $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you get that $-2E[XE[X]] = -2(E[X])^2$?

Comment: $E[X]$ is a constant, right ? Hence use $E[aX] = aE[X]$ @ThePointer

Comment: Ahh, yes, you're right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle term you have $2E(X(EX))$ not $2XEX$. Since $EX$ is a constant you get $2E(X(EX))=2(EX)(EX)=2(EX)^{2}$.